# Asp.Net (not MVC) and Visual Studio Unit Testing

Tags: asp.net, vs-unit-testing-framework

I am prepared to spend some time getting into this but it strikes as a 1 minute question for someone in the know.
  I work on an n tier application in different projects in the same solution. Normally when Visual Studio starts running both the business logic and web start at the same time.

I want to use unit tests in a weird way, I want to call a web method, which will call the business logic and hence the database, i.e. I want to use the unit test to drive the software.

Really I'd like to run the test, have breakpoints working on the test code and get the middle tier started when the tests start.

At the moment breakpoints don't appear to work and I'm not sure how to start the MT, do you have to go to the effort of exec'ing a process in code or is it built in?

Really at the beginning stage here, I'm used to nunit but not to Visual Studio unit tests.

Any suggestions?

Thanks